# How can we reconcile the difference in number of days of the unleavened feast in Deuteronomy 16:8 & Leviticus 23:6?

Tags: contradiction, deuteronomy, leviticus

Deuteronomy 16:8 (KJV)

> 8 ***Six days*** thou shalt eat unleavened bread:  and on the seventh day shall be a solemn assembly to the LORD thy God:  thou shalt do no work therein.

Leviticus 23:6 (KJV)

> 6 And on the fifteenth day of the same month is the feast of unleavened bread unto the LORD:  ***seven days*** ye must eat unleavened bread.

How can we reconcile the difference in the number of days during the feast of unleavened bread as stated in the above texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no contradiction here.  Deut. 16:8 is a clarification of what. was said previously at Deut. 16:3-4.

> Thou shalt eat no leavened bread with it; seven days shalt thou eat unleavened bread therewith, even the bread of affliction; for thou camest forth out of the land of Egypt in haste: that thou mayest remember the day when thou camest forth out of the land of Egypt all the days of thy life.
>   And there shall be no leavened bread seen with thee in all thy coast seven days; neither shall there any thing of the flesh, which thou sacrificedst the first day at even, remain all night until the morning.

In other words, Passover itself is the 14th (Ex. 12:6).  The Feast of Unleavened Bread is the following seven days from the 15th through the 21st with the 21st being the solemn assembly.

Incidentally, Lev. 23:7 informs that the 15th is also a day for solemn assembly.